# Cannot set OdbcConnection to OdbcCommand.Connection

Tags: .net, c++, odbc

On the class level, I have created reference:

System::Data::Odbc::OdbcConnection Connection;

in some method I want to set it to odbcCommand.Connection like this:

::System::Data::Odbc::OdbcCommand Command;
Command.Connection=this->Connection;

It reports "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::Data::Odbc::OdbcConnection' to 'System::Data::Common::DbConnection ^'"

I dont understand why it speaks about common::DbConnection if the Command.Connection expects OdBcConnection?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command.Connection wants a handle (^) to a System::Data::Common::DbConnection

```
public:
property OdbcConnection^ Connection {
    OdbcConnection^ get ();
    void set (OdbcConnection^ value);
}
```

Instead try to do this:

```
System::Data::Odbc::OdbcCommand Command; 
Command.Connection = %Connection;
```

The unary % operator ([Tracking reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a.aspx)) returns a CLI tracking references to a CLI object. Tracking references are valid to handles and value types.

Response to comment:

When you create a managed object this way:

```
OdbcConnection Connection;
```

It's a special type of C++/CLI object that are allocated on the stack and that points to the managed object on the managed heap. It isn't a valid managed reference object. To create a managed reference you need to do the following.

```
OdbcConnection^ Connection; // In the class definition 

// In the class constructor do the following: 
Connection = gcnew OdbcConnection();
```

And DB connection should be deleted in the constructor to guarantee timely clean up. But it is not needed for managed object, they are delete automatically

Comment: Thanks! However I do not understand why only reference is not enough.

Comment: I added the response in the answer above.